# Did God speak with Moses in a more "broken, simplified, or intimate" Hebrew dialect?

Tags: hebrew, moses

No specific Bible verse to quote, but it's something I've heard tossed around before. Can anyone confirm the validity of this claim? It went something along the lines of,

> "When Moses is writing the Pentateuch, he uses a specific form of Hebrew that is polished and refined. When he quotes himself in conversation with God, however, the Hebrew 'dialect' that YHWH and he use is like that of a husband speaking with his wife."

Comment: Related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/what-does-it-means-to-have-uncircumcised-lips/20703#20703

Comment: Curious, where does that claim come from? Who said it?

Comment: The Wiseman theory suggests that each portion ending in "these are the generations of" was written by a different author.  You have piqued my curiosity to look as possible differences in style. There are noticeable differences between the story of Joseph and the beginning chapters. If God spoke to Moses in a more primitive way, it might more closely follow the patterns of the earlier chapters.

Comment: Duplicate of https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1441/50181

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Moses Speak Broken Hebrew?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/does-moses-speak-broken-hebrew)